# Get the source code of website using lynx

Tags: bash, web, command, lynx, w3m

As I can access the source code with lynx, w3m, links, etc. protected with a form.

```
lynx -source -auth=user:pass domain.com

lynx -source -accept_all_cookies -auth=user:pass domain.com 

lynx -accept_all_cookies -auth=user:pass domain.com
```

all fail me.

thx.

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
lynx --source -accept_all_cookies -auth=user:pass "domain.com"
```

The `--` and the semicolon play the role for me sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a logon form before the page, you cannot pass it with lynx or similar applications

you should actually write some scripts. use something like **Mechanize** module either on [Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/WWW-Mechanize-1.75/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) or [Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/)!

somthing like this:

```
import mechanize

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open(YOUR URL)
browser.select_form(nr = 0)
browser.form['username'] = USERNAME
browser.form['password'] = PASSWORD
browser.submit()
```